# Response can't send redirect in catch block

Tags: java, servlets

I am writing a Servlet Controller.If I dont pass any parameter, it will catch Exception and response will sendRedirect to index.jsp

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException, Exception {
        
            response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
            RequestDAO requestDAO = new RequestDAOImpl();
               
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();) {

            // get request
            int rId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("rId"));
            Request req = requestDAO.getRequestById(rId);

            sendDispatcher(request, response, "viewRequestMentor.jsp");
        
        } catch (Exception e) {
            
            Logger.getLogger(ViewMentorRequestDetailController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
            session.setAttribute("error", "Cant view request detail");
            response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
            
        }
    }
```

But the redirect does not work and the logger display an Exception

```
Severe:   java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:518)
    at controller.ViewMentorRequestDetailController.processRequest(ViewMentorRequestDetailController.java:76)
    at controller.ViewMentorRequestDetailController.doGet(ViewMentorRequestDetailController.java:103)
```

Comment: You can't redirect after you've already started sending a response.  You need to look in the log to determine what the actual error was.

Comment: Well of course you're seeing an exception in your logs, you are trying to catch an exception - then you are immediately setting an error and setting up a "Level.SEVERE" exception. Does the redirect work AND you are seeing an exception? Because that exception is going to be displayed regardless of whether or not the redirect worked. Is there another error output to the log as well?

Comment: I don't understand. The only response I have is in the catch block. And it show the Exception as you see

Comment: @backwardforward it show two Exception a NullPointerException because I don't pass any parameter, an IllegalStateException when response try to sendRedirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is that you are using try with resources here:

```java
try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();) {
```

And that means that when the `try`/`catch` block is finished the `PrintWriter` is closed. The `PrintWriter` is what is used to print the response (the body, the headers and everything that conforms an HTTP Response), and if it is closed, no one can print anything to it.

`sendRedirect` is just a normal HTTP response with code 302 that should be written to the response object (`HttpServletResponse`), and has a header `Location` informing where it should be redirected to. If you open the "Network" tab in you browser's debug you will see that two requests are being made, one for your original `Servlet`, and another one for the redirect.

You actually don't have to close the `PrintWriter`, as it is the Servlet container (or Application Server, or whatever you are using) the responsible to do that, after everything is properly set. The `HttpServletResponse` implies much more that the things we do in the `doGet`/`doPost` methods, it has a full lifecycle in which we intervene in the middle, we receive it in the `doGet`/`doPost`/`do...` and hand it back to the next Servlet Container bean responsible to do stuff in there.

So, just remove the `try` with resources and obtain the `PrintWriter` without closing it. The redirect should then work fine.

```java
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException, Exception {
        
            response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
            RequestDAO requestDAO = new RequestDAOImpl();
               
        try {
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

            // get request
            int rId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("rId"));
            Request req = requestDAO.getRequestById(rId);

            sendDispatcher(request, response, "viewRequestMentor.jsp");
        
        } catch (Exception e) {
            
            Logger.getLogger(ViewMentorRequestDetailController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
            session.setAttribute("error", "Cant view request detail");
            response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
            
        }
    }
```